# Symbol Resolution on .NET 4.0 NGEN x64 assembly not working

Tags: .net, debugging, ngen, xperf

My symbol resolution on an x64 NGEN .NET 4.0 assembly it not working.

Details:

I have a .NET 4.0 command line assembly that I am compiling using Visual Studio with an x64 configuration. After I compile, I run NGEN (The 64 bit version) on it.

Having failed with XPERF analysing the callstacks (with -stackwalk profile) which won't resolve my symbols. I am now trying Perfmonitor from here: http://bcl.codeplex.com/releases/view/42784

I have done these steps and would have expected the call stacks to resolve:

- Start the NGEN'ed x64 app
- PerfMonitor Collect
- Perfmonitor Merge
- Perfmonitor Analyze

... Unfortunately, the stack traces don't work in PerfMonitor either.

I also tried running the app as a 32-bit - same issues. My symbols check out fine with symchk /v

I am at a loss on how to debug this broken stack trace functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand correctly, but you need to generate profilable NGEN 'assemblies'.

IOW: `ngen install ass.dll /profile`

Comment: Trying this right away. Will let you know if it fixes it. Thanks for fast reply

Comment: @ThomasKejser: You could throw in the `/debug` flag in too perhaps :)

Comment: No luck I am afraid. Still same issue

Comment: @ThomasKejser: :( I'll leave my answer here, so future people know we covered this base.

Answer (score 0):

You need the xperf Version from the Windows 8 SDK. This version supports .net. Start a trace with the new Performance Recorder UI and this tool generates PDBs for ngened .net components so that xperfview and WPA can decode the callstack.