# Can I use xperf to profile managed code?

Tags: asp.net, profiling, clr, xperf

I am trying to profile the CPU time in an ASP.NET application (running locally) using xperf.

So far, I've followed the standard procedure:

1. Run `cmd` as administrator
2. `xperf -on base`
3. Do some stuff in web app.
4. `xperf -d mylog.etl`
5. `xperfview mylog.etl`
6. Trace -> Load symbols
7. Summary table

At that point, I can see the call reports for the unmanaged code.

What do I have to do to see the same for my .NET assembly?  Is this even possible?

I have the path to my PDB in `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH`, and at least I know that the MS symbols are loaded.

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11509067/4525), but it has no resolution.  According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13685499/4525),

> You need the xperf Version from the Windows 8 SDK. This version
>   supports .net. Start a trace with the new Performance Recorder UI and
>   this tool generates PDBs for ngened .net components so that xperfview
>   and WPA can decode the callstack.

Can anyone confirm this?  I am using Windows 7 and the Windows 7 SDK.  I'm skeptical about installing another platform SDK.

**UPDATE**: Yes, the windows 8 SDK runs on Windows 7, and for this purpose, the only thing you need is the Performance Toolkit.  In fact, you don't even have to use the new "Windows Performance Analyzer", because the `etl` files generated by the new "Windows Performance Recorder" will still work with `xperfview`, including the enhanced stack traces.  See comments to accepted answer for further notes.

Comment: have you tried it now?

Comment: Related question. Can xperf profile managed Java code? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you need the Windows 8 version. Try it out and you see that it works fine. If you want to use xperf instead of WPR(UI), follow this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff357718%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will try this out.  I've been using ye olde trace statement in the meantime.

Comment: I finally tried it out, and yes, it does work on Windows 7 with .NET 4.  As your linked answer states, the recorder creates PDB files for some managed assemblies (I didn't see mine in there, but it doesn't seem to matter).  To get the kind of profile report I was looking for (time by function), I had to add the "NewThreadStack" column, and I found it helpful to clear everything else out.  Thanks again.