# Can I use xperf to profile Java managed code

Tags: java, profiling, xperf

On the lines of the question [Can I use xperf to profile managed code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746810/can-i-use-xperf-to-profile-managed-code),

can I use xperf to profile the CPU time inside Java-managed code? Currently, I see a blob like this [image] Thanks

Comment: I doubt it very much. You can use [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) to profile Java-managed code.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks. Does this work with any JDK? I am profiling a system running Oracle JDK. Thanks.

Comment: [Features](https://visualvm.github.io/features.html) *VisualVM monitors and troubleshoots applications running on Java 1.4+ from many vendors using various technologies including jvmstat, JMX, Serviceability Agent (SA) and Attach API.*

Comment: There are several issues. You need to disable frame pointer optmization to get walkable stacks and you would need to forge a synthetic pdb which knows about you JITed java methods. Another option would be to add fake .NET Runtime JIT events which from some other source know at which address the java method is located. Then WPA would be able to show proper stack traces.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. The results are not going to be useful. This tool will only profile the execution of the java.exe process which includes the JVM execution, but it doesn't know about your Java code.